# Multi task operation using threading very slow

Tags: python, multithreading

I try to make an python application which is responsible for reading and writting with plc through OPC.
The Problem which I am facing right now, I have to read some data from plc and according to that I have to write some data.
This is continuous process. So, I am using multithreading concept to handle this.
For an example:-

```html
def callallsov(self):
    while True:
        self.allsov1sobjects.setup(self.sovelementlist)

def callallmotor(self):
    while True:
        self.allmotor1dobjects.setup(self.motorelementlist)

def callallanalog(self):
    while True:
        self.allanalogobjects.setup(self.analogelementlist)

self.writsovthread = threading.Thread(target=callallsov)
self.writemotorthread = threading.Thread(target=callallmotor)
self.writemotorthread = threading.Thread(target=callallanalog)

self.writsovthread.start()

self.writemotorthread.start()

self.writeanalogthread.start()
```

calling structure:

```html
 def setup(self,elementlist):
        try:
            n =0
            self.listofmotor1D.clear()
            while n< len(self.df.index):
                self.df.iloc[n, 0] = Fn_Motor1D(self.com, self.df, elementlist, n)
                self.listofmotor1D.append(self.df.iloc[n,0])
                n = n + 1
```

```html
read and write plc tag:
            if tagname == self.cmd:

                if tagvalue == self.gen.readgeneral.readnodevalue(self.cmd):

                    # sleep(self.delaytime)

                    self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.runingFB, 1)
                else:
                    self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.runingFB, 0)

                break
```

now each elementlist have 100 device. So I make type of each element then create runtime objects for each element.
like in case of motor, if motor command is present we need to high it's runfb.
I have to follow the same process for 100 motors device.
Thus why I use while true here to check continuously data from plc.
Due to 100 motors (large amout of data) it takes long time to write in plc.plc scan cycle is very fast.
so my fist question is I haven't use join here ....is it correct?
secondly how I can avoid this sluggishness.

Comment: What you want, you can use threads in python

Comment: I already using thread but it's very slow process to update

Comment: hello...I need your support to make it through.If my question is not understable please let me know.

Comment: What motor data are you exchanging with the plc?Which plc manufacturer are you using?Is OPC mandatory or can you use other protocols?

Comment: I am using siemens plc...................which protocol you have suggested.In runtime read the current value of plc command tag and according to that on fb is high if command is activated.I have to check same process with 100 motor device continuouly

Comment: I have one doubt ...as if I am using program structure like that:self.writsovthread.start() self.writemotorthread.start() self.writemotorthread.start().....is it calling thread for sov excuted first then motor thread executed.....or three thread excuted simultaneously and independently